# Vagrant & PuPHPet: Wrong document root or misunderstanding

Tags: apache, vagrant, directory-structure, puphpet

I am new to Vagrant and just setting up some virtual machines play around with. No matter how I configure the VMs, I think I misunderstand a key concept here.

I create the Vagrantfiles using [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com), a tool that helps with getting up and running fast.

One part of the configuration is setting the correct directories.
There is one option called Box Sync Folder Source, which is et to `/.`. Another option is called Box Sync Folder Target and is set to `/var/www`. To me, that means everything in the same folder as the Vagrantfile will be synced to `/var/www`.

Then it is possible to set the Document Root. There, I entered `/var/www/public`.

After running `vagrant up`, I get the following directory structure:

```
├── default
├── html
    └── index.html [Apache "It works!"]
├── public
├── puphpet
    └── [puphpet files]
├── Vagrantfile
```

When accessing the machines IP or hostname using a web browser, I get "404 File Not Found".

That seems to make sense to me, since /public is the Document Root, and not /html, but why is there a /html folder at all? Do I need to set my Document Root to /html for the server to operate correctly?

I remember watching someone setting up a server some years ago (without PuPHPet and Vagrant of course) and I can't remember any /html directory. Also I believe the "It works!" HTML file is there to provide visual feedback that everything is up and running – why is this file placed in a folder that can't be accessed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'default' folder is the root. One way of finding out is to check your apache conf files (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/10-default-vhost_80.conf)